# How to get world coordinates?

Tags: python, 3d, camera, screen, world-coordinates

I have a camera with width and height resolution and camera parameters:

`[[position_x, position_y, position_z], 
[focal_point_x, focal_point_y, focal_point_z], 
[view_up_x, view_up_y, view_up_z]]`

Say I was given a point of the camera image plane with coordinates `x`,`y` ( `0`,`0` top left corner `width-1`, `height-1` bottom right corner).

How to get world coordinates of my point x,y from such Camera, Image data?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to bring some highlights that I found in a old book (reference at end of this answer).

First of all, you can't map directly z-axis of the world coordinate from your (x,y) image coordinate, because it's a one to many problem: one pixel point can be at any z-axis line point. However there's a lot of studies and algorithm about estimating this z-axis with just one image perspective and others using two image perspectives (stereo vision).

But if you already have the word coordinate Z axis, you can compute the the X and Y using the above formula.

[image]

where:

1. (x,y) = image coordinates of some point
2. (X0,Y0,Z0) = camera word coordinates
3. (X,Y,Z) = word coordinates of some point
4. α = angle between x and X axis
5. θ = angle between z and Z axis
6. λ = focal lenght

[image]

I'm not an expert in robotics, but maybe this can clarify your path. I use the images from below book (page 313).

**Reference book**: FU, K. S.; GONZALEZ, R. C.; LEE, C. S. G.. Robotics: control, sensing, vision and intelligence. [s. L.]: Mcgraw - Hill, 1987.

Comment: yet we do not know `Z` axis - we only now camera image plane centre `Z` coordinate...

Comment: Dont you know anything about the scene? Is it a controlled scenario? My answer points to a general solution of a unknown scene, but controlled scenarios may have a specific solution.